# Adding timestamp in XML in Oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

As part of requirement i need to create the XML message using table data,during this time I need to populate few default tags Create and expire tags.in below format using timestamp.

Create tag will =current time stamp.

Expire tag will be current time stamp + 2 min.

[image]

Can you please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one:

```
SELECT 
    XMLELEMENT("Create", TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"')),
    XMLELEMENT("Expire", TO_CHAR((SYSTIMESTAMP + interval '2' minute) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"'))
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Wernfried Domscheit, Barbaros Özhan. both of your queries helped me to achieve my requirement..

Comment: @raju ok, nice thank you, but as WernfriedDomscheit warned, it works upto seconds part(SS), excluding fractions of seconds(FF), they're rounded to zero.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, no it doesn't, the fractional seconds are preserved because he's adding an `interval`.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp i told the same thing :) there my post had that issue and ideleted it, and mentioning about that.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp  There was "your_value_of_timestamp+(1/720)" which causes problem for fractions of seconds part.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan that was on *your* answer! Wernfried's answer never had that.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp i'm telling the same thing too! Wernfriend was right and i was wrong, and It was just an explanation to raju(if you read the topmost comment of him), thanks to Wernfriend who warned me and then i deleted my post. I can't understand what you didn't understand.